# X axis in Matplotlib print random numbers instead of the years

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im new in this Pandas and Matplotlib, I follow an example from a book and apparently it give me a warning

"MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)"

and the X value of axis change from years to some random numbers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data

AMZ = data.DataReader('AMZN', start='2011', end='2018', data_source='yahoo')
AMZ = AMZ['Close']

AMZ.plot()
AMZ.resample('BA').mean().plot(style=':')
AMZ.asfreq('BA').plot(style='--')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bad interaction of MPL3.3 and pandas.  It has been fixed by both projects, but is not released yet.

Comment: To work around, simply do `plt.rcParams['date.epoch'] = '000-12-31'` and you will recover the old behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by a temporary bad interaction between Matplotlib and Pandas and is fixed in both projects.

To work around until the new versions are available:

```
plt.rcParams['date.epoch'] = '0000-12-31'
```

Comment: well it works too, but the warning is still there thou

Comment: I upgraded pandas and matplotlib to the latest versions and have no warning.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and the axis shows the correct years. The problem is not coming from the code you posted here.

[image: graph]

Comment: man how the hell? When i ran the code using PyCharm, it gave me the warning and print the wrong date, I'm lost man

Comment: Sorry I was using matplotlib 3.1.x. I upgraded it and now it shows the same error as you. Your solution might be to install an older version of matplotlib.

Comment: Well yeah I guess I need to stick with the old version, unless I get the new version of the book, probably they have a solution for this example problem

Comment: You can take a look at this. Many people seem to have the same problem. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18010

Comment: well, I already try to look for this problem like hours ago and so far I got nothing. I try to look at the matplot website and still nothing and for me asking stackoverflow was my last resort

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the link, I edited my comment.

Comment: well, apparently they haven't figure it out

Comment: I think I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data


AMZ = data.DataReader('AMZN', start='2011', end='2018', data_source='yahoo')

AMZ = AMZ['Close']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))

plt.plot(AMZ.index, AMZ, label='AMZ')
plt.plot(AMZ.resample('BA').mean().index, AMZ.resample('BA').mean(), label='resample', linestyle=':')
plt.plot(AMZ.asfreq('BA').index, AMZ.asfreq('BA'), label='asfreq', linestyle='--')

ax.set_xlabel('Date')

plt.show()
```

This should work like a charm