# Dataframe Index dtype is dtype='datetime64[ns], plot shows index year as a strange #

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an index that is YYYY/MM/DD, converted from m/d/yy after import into dataframes. I can't get the date to show up correctly in the line plot.  I think it is because matplotlib does not support dtype='datetime64[ns].

First 5 Rows of DF:

```
             Town   Cases
2020-03-21  Red Bank    2
2020-03-22  Red Bank    2
2020-03-23  Red Bank    5
2020-03-24  Red Bank    20
2020-03-26  Red Bank    20
```

the plot puts the date as the image below. But when I do a

```
covid_cnt.index = pd.to_datetime(covid_cnt.index)
covid_cnt.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

the index is listed properly as YYYY-MM-DD.  Not sure how to fix this.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-21', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-23', '2020-03-24',
           '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31',
           '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02',
           ...
           '2020-07-13', '2020-07-14', '2020-07-15', '2020-07-16',
           '2020-07-17', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-23',
           '2020-07-24', '2020-07-25'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=116, freq=None)
```

[image: d]

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078267/x-axis-in-matplotlib-print-random-numbers-instead-of-the-years/63080397?noredirect=1#comment111554181_63080397

Comment: I am learning this as we go here.. can you help me with a good site to read how to use it?

Comment: You are using it fine - as the link shows, this is a bug in matplotlib/pandas, and will be fixed.  You just need the workaround in the link.

Comment: I dont know how to use the workaround.  Today is literally my first time using pandas. Thanks for your patience. 

plt.rcParams['date.epoch'] = '0000-12-31'

Comment: I downgraded, problem solved. thanks for the link. and tips.

Answer (score 0):

What function did you use to plot the graph?  My plot (with your Town and Datetime Index) created a plot from 2020-03-15 to 2020-07-15

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'cases': [i for i in range(len(dates))],
                        'town': 'Red Bank'},
                 index=dates)
print(df.head())

            cases      town
2020-03-21      0  Red Bank
2020-03-22      1  Red Bank
2020-03-23      2  Red Bank
2020-03-24      3  Red Bank
2020-03-26      4  Red Bank
```

The first 3 values and type of the index:

```
df.index[0:3]

DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-21', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-23'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I generated a plot with the command `df.plot();` (in a Jupyter notebook).

How did you insert the screenshot?

Comment: I used covid_cnt.plot(kind='line', y ='Cases', marker = '.').  the line shows up just fine, just not the dates.
I was able to insert a png file using the pict button next to the code indicator on the comment UI.

Answer (score 0):

Given that i am very new to pandas and matplotlib downgrading to 3.2.2 solved the issue. Thanks Everyone for your help