# The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
decomposicao_aditiva = seasonal_decompose(
    df_serie_temporal, model="aditive", extrapolate_trend="freq")
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 18, 8
fig = decomposicao_aditiva.plot()
```

I am trying to plot this graph, but this error appears:

```
The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)
```

This a image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: So, what, specifically, is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078267/x-axis-in-matplotlib-print-random-numbers-instead-of-the-years

Comment: How can I solve this problem, so that the graph is plotted

Comment: @Bigben I already tried this solution

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34850

Comment: @Treton McKinney, I read all this page and the Linked pull requests. I don't understand whats is the solution

Comment: This is not an error, its a deprecation warning.  If your plot is not working its due to other issues.  Again, the stack overflow post linked by @BigBen is the solution; if that is not working, then we need more info

Comment: I am trying to plot a Time series with the airline-passengers.csv and make a model use RNN. [ https://github.com/doxdank/IGTI ]