# matplotlib.pyplot x values not displayed as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want the x values to be "yyyy-mm" from 2016-01 to 2020-01 (interval per half year). However, tried many ways the x values still in a mess. 
My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

df = pd.read_csv('fcc-forum-pageviews.csv',index_col='date')
df = df[(df['value'] >= df['value'].quantile(0.025)) & (df['value'] <= df['value'].quantile(0.975))]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figwidth(15)
fig.set_figheight(9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_title('Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Page Views')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax.plot(df['value'],color='r')
```

The following is the result:
[image]

However, what I expected should be:
[image]

The dataset can be downloaded from [here](https://repl.it/@freeCodeCamp/fcc-time-series-visualizer#fcc-forum-pageviews.csv).Any help is highly appreciated.

After **@r-beginners** help, I have updated the code as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

df = pd.read_csv('fcc-forum-pageviews.csv',index_col='date')
df = df[(df['value'] >= df['value'].quantile(0.025)) & (df['value'] <= df['value'].quantile(0.975))]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figwidth(15)
fig.set_figheight(9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_title('Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Page Views')
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df.index)))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(len(df.index)))
months = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
ax.plot(df['value'], color='r')
```

now it can display the x values in 6-month interval. However, instead of starting from 2016-07 (the date from the dataframe), it starts from 1970-02. Any hints? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date data to `pd.to_datetime()`
You can use MonthLocator to control it. The interval is set to 6 months.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

df = pd.read_csv('fcc-forum-pageviews.csv',index_col='date')
df = df[(df['value'] >= df['value'].quantile(0.025)) & (df['value'] <= df['value'].quantile(0.975))]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figwidth(15)
fig.set_figheight(9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_title('Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Page Views')
# ax.set_xticks(range(len(df.index)))
# ax.set_xticklabels(range(len(df.index)))
# months = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
# months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax.plot(df['value'], color='r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can see the interval is 6 months now. However, the starting yyyy-month was 1970-02 instead of the year-month from the dataframe (should be 2016-07). Do you know why? What is wrong with 
ax.plot(df.index, df['value'], color='r')? seems the x values was not starting from the date in the dataset

Comment: I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078267/x-axis-in-matplotlib-print-random-numbers-instead-of-the-years) may be the cause of the problem, but even after dealing with it, it didn't get it right. Are you also 'matplotlib:3.3.0'?

Comment: Yes, the version is 'matplotlib:3.3.0'

Comment: The cause was elsewhere. The dates were not in chronological form. Fixed the code.

Comment: You can do this simply by converting the next date/time format to `pd.to_datetime()` in your original code.

Comment: Thanks. Seems this is an issue in 'matplotlib:3.3.0'. After added pd.to_datetime(), I got the issue the same issue as you mentioned above. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078267/x-axis-in-matplotlib-print-random-numbers-instead-of-the-years)

Comment: What is your version of pandas? I was able to see successfully with 'pandas:1.1.0' with only the date conversion.

Comment: Thanks! Updated to pandas 1.1.0. It can show the year-month properly. But it starts from 2016-04 instead of 2016-07. Is there any way to make the x value starting from a specified year-month? Anyway, I rated this as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: When you convert the date to `pd.to_datetime()` in your first code, instead of using the 'MonthLocator' I presented, does it not show from '2016-07'?

Comment: The first record's date was 2016-05-09. I don't know why it starts from 2016-04 instead of 2016-05. As the interval should be 6 months, I hope to make it starts from 2016-07. I have updated the code in question which it is the latest code I used.

Comment: I have commented out the unnecessary code and updated the code. I've also attached the graph created with the new code.

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [Xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

From the docs

```
>>> locs, labels = xticks()  # Get the current locations and labels.
>>> xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))  # Set label locations.
>>> xticks(np.arange(3), ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Sue'])  # Set text labels.
>>> xticks([0, 1, 2], ['January', 'February', 'March'],
...        rotation=20)  # Set text labels and properties.
>>> xticks([])  # Disable xticks.
```